# SQL Server: computed column to allow for adjustments?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, powerapps

I have a computed column known as `TotalTime`. This column is populated using the `DATEDIFF` function from two datapoints that we are getting entered in from Microsoft PowerApps - `StartTime` and `EndTime`.

However, sometimes it would be nice to be able to make adjustments to the calculation. For example, if the PowerApps user selects a certain control, it would add five minutes to `TotalTime`.

This doesn't necessarily have to come from PowerApps itself - but could be a stored proc or function. What is the cleanest way to do this without having to break the computed column?

Comment: Adjust the value in the query used to select the data.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, could you elaborate a little more on your comment? Should I adjust the value of the columns used to compute in order to reflect the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new column (`TotalTimeAdjustment`) reserved for admin adjustment. This will be normally NULL (or can be defaulted to 0). Modify your calculated column to include `TotalTimeAdjustment` column as the 3rd input alongside `StartTime` and `EndTime`. Whenever an adjustment is needed the admin can update `TotalTimeAdjustment` for the relevant record(s).